# Grails GORM stops working after redeployment because can not load data from DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

After our application redeployment, we sometimes see a problem when the whole GORM stops working with a weird reason

```
25-Apr-2021 07:00:45.351 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 48663 ms
25-04-2021 07:00:47 ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/api/<any request>] due to exception [No row with the given identifier exists: [com.test.auth.Role#1001]]
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.test.auth.Role#1001]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:176)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.proxy.SimpleHibernateProxyHandler.unwrapProxy(SimpleHibernateProxyHandler.java:79)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapProxy(GrailsHibernateUtil.java:390)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils$_handleLazyProxy_closure1.doCall(HibernateUtils.groovy:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
...
```

This problem appears randomly and can be raised by any first API request (or Quartz job run) after redeployment and can be related to any domain class in the system.
The data is correct in DB and all "native" SQL queries work without any problems.

We have no locks on DB (can do any SQL query to any mentioned table) and ~10 instances of Grais web services connected to the same DB. Also, we have

```
dbCreate: none
```

for all instances

Any thoughts about the possible reason? This issue is causing us tremendous problems during the deployment process.

- Grails version 3.1.16
- MySQL 5.7 (Aurora)

Comment: This appears to be an issue with your test... specifically ROLE. This may depend on how you are accessing ROLE. Normally you don't access ROLE directly; you access through UserRole/PersonRole. You can also more easily access ROLE through the 'principal' (springSecurityService.principal.authorities*)

Comment: @Orubel this problem can be with any domain class in the system, not only Role, any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using any caching in those domain classes? `No row with the given identifier exists` means that hibernate tries to reach an object which doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @Eugene For arguments sake, can I see another error showing what you describe? And can you create show the test as well?

Comment: When this happens, does an object of the class with the ID from the error exist?  (In your question, is there a Role with ID 1001?)  I'm concerned since you say you have 10 services connected to the same database...feels like they're probably modifying each others' data and cached hibernate objects are a symptom.  I would definitely disable caching as a data point for testing.

Comment: @Daniel of course we have the role with ID 1001 in DB, and we have no modification related to this class during the application startup

Comment: Can you either disable caching, or create a copy of the database and point only one application at it?  Either of those tests would help you narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: @Daniel this class has hibernate cache (cache true) enabled. Do you think it can be the reason? We can not disable it because it will affect performance.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you disable this in your development system as a debugging method.  Once you know whether that's the issue or not, then you can proceed with making changes to fix the issue in a performant way.